# To sum up same keys values in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, key

I have below array which has to sum up same keys values as {'dogs' => 11, 'cats' => 3}.

```
animals = [['dogs', 4], ['cats', 3], ['dogs', 7]]
```

I have found the below answer while I was searching on stackoverflow (I lost the link:( )

```
print animals.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k, v), h| h[k] += v }
```

However I can't make it clear in my mind that what do k,v and h represents exactly. Because "h" is staying second argument of the block code but it continious with h[k] . Could anyone explain the code clearly?

Thank you too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms:

```
animals.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(key, value), hash|
  hash[key] += value
end
```

Here `(k,v)` is an expansion of each pair in the `animals` hash, which is *key-value*. `h` represents the "object" that's passed along with this iteration.

That's a fairly standard pattern in terms of Ruby code.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply. What do I suppose to add above code simply to print the result at cmd (I mean for "do", "end" syntax)?

Comment: In Ruby there's `puts` which is used to display strings. If you assign the result of this to a variable you can do `puts result.inspect` where `result` is what you assign. The debug-friendly `p` method is even simpler, `p result` is equivalent to that other version.

Answer (score 2):

```
animals.map(&:dup).
        group_by(&:shift).
        map { |k, v| [k, v.flatten.inject(:+)] }.
        to_h
#⇒ {"dogs"=>11, "cats"=>3}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking of doing, but it does look a lot like alchemy when expressed fully. It also creates a lot more garbage than `each_with_object` does.

Comment: @tadman indeed, but what I was thinking in the first place, was already provided in your answer, so I was up to come with something different. I definitely would vote for yours answer.

Comment: Also isn't `Enumerable#sum` specifically a `rails` method? Since there is no `rails` tag here maybe `reduce(:+)` would be more fitting.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with the Array to understand it better

```
animals.each {|arr| puts arr.inspect }
# ["dogs", 4]
# ["cats", 3]
# ["dogs", 7]

animals.each {|k, v| puts "k -> #{k}, v -> #{v}" }
# k -> dogs, v -> 4
# k -> cats, v -> 3
# k -> dogs, v -> 7

animals.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h| 
  puts "k -> #{k}, v -> #{v}, h -> #{ h.inspect }"
end
# k -> dogs, v -> 4, h -> {}
# k -> cats, v -> 3, h -> {}
# k -> dogs, v -> 7, h -> {}

animals.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
  h[v] = k
  puts "k -> #{k}, v -> #{v}, h -> #{ h.inspect }"
end
# k -> dogs, v -> 4, h -> {4=>"dogs"}
# k -> cats, v -> 3, h -> {4=>"dogs", 3=>"cats"}
# k -> dogs, v -> 7, h -> {4=>"dogs", 3=>"cats", 7=>"dogs"}
```